# Problema con consulta y php/ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

Queria pedir ayuda con un problema que tengo y no he podido encontrar el error, en realidad son 2 problemas:

Problema 1: Tengo error con la consulta, tengo un error de syntaxis (no se como llegue a eso pero antes tampoco me funcionaba)

Problema 2: Este problema no puedo saber a que se debe, lo que pasa es que tengo un valor en un campo (de las variables que recibo con post) que es F++ pero cuando recibo el valor y lo imprimo en consola solo me muestra la F sin el ++, en realidad ningún valor que mande por el post con + es recibido y por esto creo que no podre realizar la consulta normalmente, si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho.

```
<?php

$especiee = $_POST["especiee"];
$generoo = $_POST["generoo"];
$familiaa = $_POST["familiaa"];
$calidadd = $_POST["calidadd"];
$tamañoo = $_POST["tamañoo"];
$ciudadd = $_POST["ciudadd"];
$comentarioo = $_POST["comentarioo"];
$precioo = $_POST["precioo"];
$especie = $_POST["especie"];
$genero = $_POST["genero"];
$familia = $_POST["familia"];
$calidad = $_POST["calidad"];
$tamaño = $_POST["tamaño"];
$ciudad = $_POST["ciudad"];
$comentario = $_POST["comentario"];
$precio = $_POST["precio"];


$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','shells');


$consulta="update shell set especie='$especiee', 
genero='$generoo',familia='$familiaa',calidad='$calidadd',tamano='$tamañoo',
ciudad='$ciudadd',comentario='$comentarioo',precio='$precioo' where especie='$especie' 
and genero=$'$genero'and familia='$familia'and calidad='$calidad'and tamano='$tamaño'and 
ciudad='$ciudad'and comentario='$comentario'and precio='$precio' "

$request=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta); 

if($request) echo "funciona";
else echo "error";  

?>
```

Comment: Error 1: `genero=$'$genero'` (el $) ... Error2: `.... precio='$precio' "` falta cerrarlo con punto y coma `.... precio='$precio' ";`

Comment: que soy tonto, gracias!!! es que entre tanto cambio creo que deje una versión antigua y ahi tenia esos errores por eso no los pude ver jaja de todos modos pero el error que tengo es que no me funciona la consulta y creo que es por eso del f++ y además me acabo de dar cuenta que las variables se me guardan con unos espacios :/

Comment: Denada....Tendrías que mostrar entonces el código relevante.. es decir la parte del `f++`...

Comment: Lo estoy publicando de nuevo, te pasaste, de verdad muchas gracias!

Answer (score -1):

No estas concatenando las variables en php la sintaxis para concatenar un string con una variable es con el operador punto (`.`): `$str= 'blabla'.$variable;`

Si no queres concatenar tenes que usar comillas dobles así: `$str="blabla $variable"` o `$str ="balbal {$variable}";`.

También estoy viendo que tenes algunas `keys` del arreglo `post` con una letra duplicada; no se si será así o ni idea; habría que ver como estás mandando los datos del cliente si es eso.

Para depurar o encontrar errores podes diseccionar la *query*; hacela mas chica y anda agregándole valores de a poco; donde te tire el error, ahí esta el problema.

Podría ayudar poniendo que error te tira *php* para darte una mejor ayuda.

Aclaración: el arreglo `POST` si recibe todos los caracteres que le mandes. Trata de verificar en el cliente el valor de esa variable.

No sabría darte una solución porque falta información amigo.

¿Cómo estás pasando los datos? ¿por un formulario o por *ajax*? si es alguno de esos, trata de verificar el valor de la variable con *javascript* antes de mandar y asegurate de que sean correctos. También podes ver en la sección de red en en panel de *admin para desarrolladores*, apretando el <kbd>F12</kbd>, en la sección de red, mira esa petición, te vas a la pestaña de parámetros y ahí salen todos los parámetros que le estas pasando al script.

Comment: Si falta información, puedes utilizar la sección de comentarios para pedir aclaraciones y escribir la respuesta cuando el AP haya mejorado su pregunta. Por favor, lee [answer] y [ask]. Un saludo.

Comment: Por favor, tratemos de evitar los modismos ya que estamos en un sitio que incluye varios tipos de español. (yo se que no es ofensivo, pero para alguien que desconoce algunos terminos lo puede sentir a mal).